# Backup disk, to be activated and mounted only once a day

Tags: mount, backup, cron, disk

I run a small Kubuntu system, and have an external USB backup disk array (RAID) that syncs (with rsync) to the internal disks once a day. Problem is that the external enclosure (RAID) spins the discs down, and up again after about 5 minutes. Using
    `hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/a94a1377-......`
I can let all the external disks in the enclosure spindown, but after five minutes, same story again... I tried to synchronice the timing, and have another crontab spindown the discs just before they would startup again, but the timing is always off. It helps a bit, but not enough to be silent during the day. Also: I don't want to spindown when the rsync is making a backup copy...
Any suggestions? Most questions I found (and answers) deal with the reverse situation, but I mount/umount when needed inside crontab, and the disks should be silent when not needed.
The enclosure is an Orico 5 disks USB3.0 port which supports 8TB discs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little digging and the best solution to your specific problem I found was: [Prevent a USB external hard drive from sleeping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/prevent-a-usb-external-hard-drive-from-sleeping).

There are four answers but what I like the best is a comment suggesting a `cron` job that executes:

```
*/15 * * * * date > /mnt/disk/.date`
```

Please review all answers though and, as always, if clarification is needed don't hesitate to post a comment below!

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer, but like I said, I really want the disks to spinup only once a day, I don't want them active during the day, in crontab I unmount the disk again, just to let them 'wild, and running free', which normally would result in spindown. Problem is: after 5 minutes the spinup again, without any activity on the server side (I checked the log files, can't find any action on an unmounted external drive). The enclosure shows some lights, I can hear (and see) the disks spinning up, and after a while spindown again.

Comment: @user780770 Sorry I thought you didn't want them spinning down because you needed to backup. Are you saying they are spinning up even when they aren't mounted and that is the basic problem?

Comment: In fact, yes, the backup crontab script will take care of mounting etc. It's just the spinups in between that are the problem. I want the disks asleep until the next backup.

Comment: @user780770 Aww *light turns on*. A `udev` rule to power off the device or bus or something is required then. I'll put on my thinking cap and probably change the answer tomorrow. Can you update your question with `lsusb` output and annotate the RAID array?

Comment: lsusb gives me:    Bus 004 Device 008: ID 152d:0567 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS567 SATA 6Gb/s bridge

Comment: @user780770 I don't have a full answer yet but I just wanted to update you on `udev` research: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment

Comment: Thanks for the link. Haven't even crossed my mind to disable usb devices based on vendor, I was more looking into hibernate/deactivate one specific usb device. I'll look into it more :)

Comment: @user780770 Further research for usb drives is auto-suspend usb port can lead to data corruption on some drives: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend

Comment: To be honest, after a bit of necessary upgrading (17.04 to 17.10), the hard drive rack behaves as it is supposed to behave. Wakes at exactly 03:00, reads the harddrives, rsyncs all, and suspends the backup drives again. That is how I wanted it to be, the only exception being an extra (requested) email from crontab to show that the backup drives have received a suspend command again.
This also includes an error message "*Archive is mounted on /media/orico
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*"

Comment: I read thoroughly through the USB data corruption part, but couldn't find anything which applies to my situation. Good to know though that USB drives can't be 'thrusted'. Kudos @WinEunuuchs2Unix!

Comment: @user780770 I'm glad it's finally working. When your question was first posted you may have been on kernel `4.13.0-26` which had many problems and now you are probably on kernel `4.13.0-32` which has many fixes.

Comment: I agree that it might have just been the kernel, it was working on the 'old' server version 17.04, and it happened just after a harddisk error (server is on 24/7) which caused linux to refuse starting up, reformatted, put Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu up, and then the problem started. Although I got many years experience in problem solving, never expected it to be something 'simple' as a kernel.... But agreed, problem seems to be gone after the 17.10 upgrade. I am happy it works :)